# Negative Questions:

Tags: verbs, questions

You have a large house.

Negative question= Don't you have a large house?

Saying ''Haven't you a large house?'' is wrong am i correct?

But is ''Haven't you got a large house?'' correct or wrong?

Comment: Do you have a particular version of English you're aiming for? I feel like all three are valid options in different dialects of English.

Comment: I'd say that 'Haven't you a house?' is unnatural-sounding on both sides of the Atlantic, but 'Hasn't he a beautiful smile' (probably as a statement rather than a question) is quite acceptable in the UK at least.

Comment: In the US, using *haven't* or *hasn't* in this way is likely to sound like you're trying to act out or mock a British or fancy accent (a British stereotype in America). So in the US, unless this is actually your intent, I'd stick with option 1.

Answer (score 1):

"Don't you have a large house?" is the typical way of writing it.

"Haven't you a large house?" is a bit archaic, but not wrong. Poetic license.

"Haven't you got a large house?" is relatively informal, more likely to be heard spoken than read. Which makes sense, it sounds better. "Don't you have a large house?" reads better.

Answer (score 0):

All three are grammatically correct. There might be slight nuances of meaning depending on context but they would all be understood perfectly well (at least in BrEng). I don't see anything archaic in the usage.

They could be used in a straightforward question, for example:
Some people are discussing the advantages and drawbacks of having a large house and one says to another "Don't *you* have a large house?" [meaning - I think I remember that you have large house, am I correct?]

Or they might be used rhetorically, and can be followed by ! rather than ?. For example:
You are visiting an acquaintance's house for the first time and are surprised at how big it is and comment "Don't you have a large house!"

NB If you are making a straight request for information you would not use the negative but would ask "Do you have/Have you got a large house?"

Answer (score 0):

Let me try the following:

*Affirmative*:   you have / you have got
*Negative*: you do not have (you don't have) / you have not got (you haven't got)
*Interrogative*: do you have? / have you got?
*Interrogative-negative*: don't you have? / have you not got (haven't you got?)

It may now be easier to see what's incorrect and why. By the way, all your three examples are correct. It's all a matter of what exactly you wish to say and how, as there're choices.